# Efficient combinations of combinations

Tags: python, combinations

I need all combinations of a set of combinations with an increasing length.
The first set is created like this:

```
combinations = list(itertools.combinations(5, 2))
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)]
```

Then, all combinations matching a specific condition are stored in matches:

```
[(0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (3, 4)]
```

Out of those, I want to find all intersecting combinations with length 3:

```
[(0, 3, 4)]
```

i only need to find combinations intersecting with each other. [(0, 3), (0, 4), (3, 4)] are intersecting, so [(0, 3, 4)] is a combination. [(0, 2, 4)] is not, since (2,4) are not intersecting

At the moment I'm using:

```
 combinations = []
 for y in matches:
      for x in matches:
          if y != x:
             el = qsort(unique(y[:] + x[:]))
             if el not in combinations and len(el) == it:
                  combinations.append(el)
```

But working with combinations with more than 200 numbers takes too long.  Is there a way to do this faster?

Comment: You are comparing what with what?

Comment: That is, you are looking for all cycles of length 3 in a graph whose vertices are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 and whose edges correspond to the chosen combinations.

Comment: What do you mean by `find all intersecting combinations with length 3` ?

Comment: Probably it takes too long because your solution is O(n²). It is hard to suggest an optimized version without knowing the problem.

Comment: i only need to find combinations intersecting with each other. [(0, 3), (0, 4), (3, 4)] are intersecting, so [(0, 3, 4)] is a combination. [(0, 2, 4)] is not, since (2,4) are not intersecting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As chepner suggested, i was looking for all cycles or cliques in this graph. Networkx's enumerate_all_cliques() is an easy way to find them.